# New Scope in Coq

Tags: coq

I'd like my own scope, to play around with long distfixes.

```
Declare Scope my_scope.
Delimit Scope my_scope with my.
Open Scope my_scope.

Definition f (x y a b : nat) : nat := x+y+a+b.
Notation "x < y * a = b" := (f x y a b)
 (at level 100, no associativity) : my_scope.

Check (1 < 2 * 3 = 4)%my.
```

How do you make a new scope?

EDIT: I chose "x < y * a = b" to override Coq's operators (each with a different precedence).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Didn't you just make your own scope? How is what you did not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The command `Declare Scope` does not exist.  The various commands about scopes are described in [section 12.2 of the Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#scopes).

Your choice of an example notation has inherent problems, because it clashes with pre-defined notations, which seem to be used before your notation.

When looking at the first components the parser sees `_ < _`  and thinks that you are actually talking about comparison of integers, then it sees the second part as being an instance of the notation `_ * _`, then it sees that all that is the left hand side of an equality. And all along the parser is happy, it constructs an expression of the form:

```
(1 < (2 * 3)) = 4
```

This is constructed by the parser, and the type system has not been solicited yet.  The type checker sees a natural number as the first child of `(_ < _)` and is happy.  It sees `(_ * _)` as the second child and it is happy, it now knows that the first child of that product should be a nat number and it is still happy; in the end it has an equality, and the first component of this equality is in type `Prop`, but the second component is in type `nat`.

If you type `Locate "_ < _ * _ = _".` the answer tells you that you did define a new notation.  The problem is that this notation never gets used, because the parser always finds another notation it can use before.  Understanding why a notation is preferred to another one requires more knowledge of parsing technology, as alluded to in Coq's manual, chapter 12, in the sentence (obscure to me):

*Coq extensible parsing is performed by Camlp5 which is essentially a LL1 parser*.

You have to choose the levels of the various variables, `x`, `y`, `a`, and `b` so that none of these variables will be able to match too much of the text.  For instance, I tried defining a notation close to yours, but with a starting and an ending bracket (and I guess this simplifies the task greatly).

```
Notation "<< x < y * a = b >>" := (f x y a b)
 (x at level 59, y at level 39, a at level 59) : my_scope.
```

The level of `x` is chosen to be lower than the level of `=`, the level of y is chosen to be lower than the level of `*`, the level of `a` is chosen to be lower than `=`.  The levels were obtained by reading the answer of the command `Print Grammar constr.`  It seems to work, as the following command is accepted.

```
Check << 1 < 2 * 3 = 4 >>.
```

But you may need to include a little more engineering to have a really good notation.

Comment: i did want my silly 4-ary operator to shadow coq's. there's no way to drop the bracketing? "<< x < y * a = b" says "cannot determine level" while "x < y * a = b >>" says "The level of the leftmost non-terminal cannot be changed". does this have to do with the "essentially an LL1 parser"?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question in your title:

The new scope gets created when you declare a notation that uses it.  That is, you don’t declare a new scope `my_scope` separately.  You just write

```
Notation "x <<< y" := (f x y) (at level 100, no associativity) : my_scope.
```

and that declares a new scope `my_scope`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers for this question only apply to older versions of Coq. I'm not sure when it started but in at least Coq 8.13.2, Coq prefers the user to first use `Declare Scope` create a new scope. What the OP has in their code is Coq's preferred way to declare scopes now.

See the [current manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#coq:cmd.Open-Scope)